# How can I limit posts to my parse.com database based on time of day?

Tags: android, parse-platform

My app allows users to save a "guess" about something to a database on parse, but I want to cut off these guesses at a certain time, say for example 5:00 PM CST, and also prevent multiple submissions from the same person. Any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `beforeSave` function in Cloud Code and reject any saves that are outside of your timespan.

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers

Comment: Do you know where I can download whatever libraries I need to use these methods in my android app? I don't see them on the page, I'll keep looking. (I have the Parse android libraries and I'm using the user and object classes without issues, but I'm thinking maybe I need something else to use their javascript methods in android?)

Comment: Cloud Code runs server-side on Parse, you simply create your beforeSave triggers and reject saves that occur outside of your time window, duplicate submissions etc.. All you need for this is the Parse CLI (to deploy the Cloud Code) https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line. And the docs for the JavaScript SDK https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide.

Comment: I guess I understand that the code runs serverside, where I'm lost is that when I try to do something like their example

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave .....


I get an error on the .Cloud. part of the first line, "Cannot resolved symbol Cloud" I had to import some Parse.jar to be able to use parse classes before, do i need a different one too to use this? I don't see a download.

Comment: I don't get where I'm supposed to put my JavaScript code I think is the problem, I get errors putting it in with my Java code for my app.

Comment: You don't need to add the JavaScript to your app. You deploy it to parse.com using the CLI and it will run automatically every time an object of that class is saved

Comment: Ok I figured out what I needed to do in CMD to set things up for my app and ran the simple "Hello world" tutorial inside my app and it worked :) thanks for the help. I'm pretty unfamiliar with JavaScript so I'm not sure how I can check time within a method but I'll look it up.

Comment: Have a look at moment.js for this, makes working with dates a piece of cake.